# This rule admits/allows no exceptions. Which do you use

Tags: word-choice

> This rule allows no exceptions.

This sounds natural to me, but I am told "The rule admits no exceptions" can be an alternative way to express this. However, some say using admits is not correct or natural.

I would like to ask how you feel it.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the correct phrase would be-

> This rule *allows* no exceptions.

The usage of *admit* in place of *allow* would sound very odd and is possibly incorrect therefore you should refrain from using it, instead stick with *allow*.

People who believe that *admit* can be correct are possibly influenced by the quote:

"No rule is so general, which admits not some exception." - Robert Burton

The context in which Robert Burton said is most probably different to what you think are *rules* and thus should not be mixed up.

Comment: It sounds slightly old-fashioned to me, but not odd, and it definitely isn't incorrect.

Comment: @Useless In this context, "admit" is a lot more common followed by "of."

Comment: It's relatively formal, and some (not me) might say it's dated, but [*"{This rule} rule admits **of** no exceptions"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rule+admits+of+no+exceptions%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is perfectly valid English. So -1 for saying it's *"very odd and is possibly incorrect"* - the only thing that's even slightly "unusual" is that we nearly always include ***of*** in that construction. Citing a *definitely* archaic excerpt from Robert Burton is not helpful in this context.

Comment: @Elian - I'd agree it's probably more common, but that's very different to saying the suggested form is _possibly incorrect_ ... which is factually is not.

Comment: Whether its common or not is more of a question regarding regional language usage; as such I find *allows* to be much more common than *admit* in that context and the latter is very rarely used in my country.

Comment: @Useless It indeed is not. Still, "admit" alone is a rarer usage than "allow" and "allow/admit of." The latter sounds more idiomatic and makes more sense to me, as long as a rule or law doesn't "allow" or "admit" something, but "allow" or "admit" (the existence) "of" something.

Answer (score 1):

"Allow" is the more common usage.

Alternately to *This rule allows no exceptions*, you can also say:

> *This rule [allows of](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/allow-of-sth) no exceptions.*
>
> *This rule [admits of](https://www.nytimes.com/books/first/l/lapham-rules.html) no exceptions.*

[allow](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/allow-of-sth); [admit](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/admit?s=t) (often followed by *of*): to permit something to happen: *This rule allows of no exceptions; The evidence allows of only one interpretation*.

> Sources: Cambridge Dictionary and Random House

Comment: I have to disagree with that first sentence. According to Google Books, ["rule admits of no exceptions"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rule+admits+of+no+exceptions%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) occurs **1270** times in their corpus, but the same search string with ***allow*** gets only 4 hits. And lest you say that's because I added the extra preposition ***of***, note that if I remove it, I get just 8 hits for ***admits***, and 10 hits for ***allows***. In short, ***admits of*** is ***by far the most common form***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Admit of" is indeed by far the most common form. That said, "rule allows of" is perfectly grammatical and cited in both BrE and AmE dictionaries online.

Comment: @Fumblefingers As an aside, the first sentence is meant by comparison with "admit" alone, not "admit of." Otherwise, I would have used "the most" instead of "the more" common usage. It's a mere direct answer to the OP.

Comment: Go on - I'll bite. Please post links showing "both BrE and AmE dictionaries online" citing "rule allows of" as a typical construction. Without ***of***, both ***admit*** and ***allow*** are so rare in this exact context I find it hard to believe any dictionaries would go to the trouble of pointing out that such usages are "valid" (which I don't dispute, btw - I'm just saying they're idiomatically *not preferred*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers What is CD for you? a load of baloney? :-) http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/allow-of-sth

Comment: What can I say? I can hardly take issue with CD for defining what is after all a "valid" usage. But in the context of [actual usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=allows+of+no%2Cadmits+of+no&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Callows%20of%20no%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadmits%20of%20no%3B%2Cc0), I stand by my downvote - which is entirely directed at the first sentence in this answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I wouldn't mind editing my answer to make the first sentence sound clearer, but what you seem to be implying here is that I would support "allow" as a more common form than "admit of." Where in my answer did you read that? Neither of "allow of" or "admit of" are implied in my first sentence. As a direct answer to the OP, I'm just stating that "allow" is more common than "admit."

Answer (score 1):

Per my comments to other answers, the overwhelmingly preferred form is ***admits of***...

> *This rule admits **of** no exceptions* [1270 hits in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rule%20admits%20of%20no%20exceptions%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22rule%20admits%20of%20no%20exceptions%22&tbm=bks)
>   *This rule allows **of** no exceptions* [4 hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rule%20admits%20of%20no%20exceptions%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22rule%20allows%20of%20no%20exceptions%22&tbm=bks)
>   *This rule admits no exceptions* [8 hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rule%20admits%20of%20no%20exceptions%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22rule%20admits%20no%20exceptions%22&tbm=bks)
>   *This rule allows no exceptions* [10 hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rule%20admits%20of%20no%20exceptions%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22rule%20allows%20no%20exceptions%22&tbm=bks)

Obviously there's no difference in meaning - this is purely a matter of established idiomatic usage.

Answer (score 0):

There are two senses of *admit* which make perfect sense in this phrase, and I'm honestly not sure which is more relevant.

1. it could be *admit - acknowledge the existence of*, so we have

   > This rule admits *(the existence of)* no exceptions

   which is to say, this **descriptive** rule claims no exceptions to the rule exist.
2. or it could be *admit - permit entry to*, giving

   > This rule admits no exceptions *(entry into the subject under discussion)*

   which would be a **prescriptive** rule explicitly disallowing exceptions.

However, they're both entirely valid, if a little old-fashioned